# Adding a type definition for a JSON file in typescript

Tags: json, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have a configuration file `config.json` that lives in my typescript project that I want to add strong typing for.

**src/config.json**

```
{
   "id": "some-id-string",
   "data": { 
     "somekey" : "some value"
  }
}
```

In order to add the typing, I added an `index.d.ts` file to my project as well:

**src/index.d.ts**

```js
declare module 'config.json' {
  export const id: string;
  export const data: Record<string, string>;
}
```

However it doesn't seem to work, as I can add arbitrary fields to my config.json and typescript is happy to let them through, ie:

**src/config.json**

```
{
   "id": "some-id-string",
   "foo": "bar", // <-- typescript doesn't catch this
   "data": { 
     "somekey" : "some value"
  }
}
```

I've created this project using `create-react-app` with the typescript flag, which produces the following `tsconfig.json`:

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

I think I'm missing some small step here, but I'm not sure and I couldn't find many examples of how this is done.

**EDIT:**
It seems like this is doable, given that the `tsconfig.json` itself has strong typing:

[image: strongly typed json]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "strong typing" provided in the `tsconfig.json` file is not actually the work of TypeScript at all!

Instead, VSCode is using a built-in JSONSchema integration to provide type hints for json files. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/json

Many open-source libraries provide JSON schemas for there configs, eg: webpack, eslint, etc.. (https://schemastore.azurewebsites.net/json/)

Answer (score 5):

Typescript will not validate your json. It only works in `.ts` and `.tsx` files.

What your `d.ts` there will do is assume that the data imported from `config.json` conforms to your type, but it will not actually ensure that since json files are outside of typescript's domain.

A workaround would be to put this config in a `config.ts` file instead with something like:

```
// config.ts
export default {
  //...
} as MyDataFormat
```

Comment: Does this mean that `tsconfig.json` is somehow special? See edit in OP.

Comment: Interesting point! I think that file may just be special, and I could be wrong. But I've not heard of a typescript feature that allows this with custom schemas/files.

Comment: Did a bit more digging, and it looks like VSCode has built in JSONSchema support, so you are correct in that it is not TypeScript that is providing these hints, but the code editor: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/json

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem by not using plain json file as config but by importing a config *module* dynamically:

script_with_config.ts:

```
type MyConfig = {
  someConfigValue: string;
};

type ConfigModule = {
  [configName: string]: MyConfig;
};

export default MyConfig;

const configFile = "myConfigFile.ts";
import(configFile).then((loadedConfigs: ConfigModule) => {
  const config: MyConfig | undefined = loadedConfigs["default"];
  console.log(config?.someConfigValue);
});
```

Then using the exported config type in my config file

myConfigFile.ts:

```
import MyConfig from "./script_with_config";

export const someConfig: MyConfig = {
  someConfigValue: "foo",
};

export default someConfig;

export const someOtherConfig: MyConfig = {
  someConfigValue: "bar",
};
```

Note that config will be available not only with `loadedConfigs["default"]` but with `loadedConfigs["someConfig"]` as well (since it is exported by that way, too). So you could export several configs in one file, like in this case you could reach the other config with `loadedConfigs["someOtherConfig"]` and it would log "bar" to the console.

Of course you must either compile the config file as well or (like I did) use ts-node to execute the script.